Changing Workspace shortcuts (SHIFT + F3, F1, F12)
I was wondering whether it's possible to change the workspace shortcuts such as Shift+F3? Currently it takes me through all node editor workspaces which means often I have to cycle through, Compositing, GeoNodes, Texture Node Editor and finally the Shader Editor which is the one I would like to use the shortcut for. Cycling through all of these makes me rather want to use the Editor Type button but if I could disable these other editor types being linked to the shortcut that would be great.
I can't seem to find it in the preferences.
